# How do I get the data from an ID2D1Bitmap

Tags: direct2d

I am rendering to a ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget from witch I can get a ID2D1Bitmap.
But how can I get the pixel data?

Comment: An ID2D1Bitmap is a GPU resource. Accessing pixels on GPU is inneficient (that's why it's not easy). What do you want to do with these pixels?

Comment: I have made a small Direct2D game and I want the frame data to put into a neural network.